# Problems with biblatex and chicago: Parentheses around issue and duplicated year

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I have some problems with creating a bibliography adhering entirely to the Chicago style with `biblatex`. Namely, the issue of journal articles does not appear in parentheses but after the volume separated with a dot (for example "8.1" instead of "8(1)"). Also for every `@Misc` or `@Book` entry the year seems to appear twice.

This would be my code:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            citestyle=chicago-authordate,
            doi=false,
            backend=biber, 
            maxnames=2,
            ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{document}

   \printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

I know that I could use `biblatex-chicago` instead, but unfortunately I do need some features of `biblatex` for example to divide the bibliography into different parts.

Did I make any mistake in the package specification or is there a way to fix this manually?

Comment: Your code can not be used for tests as no bib entries are provided. If possible use examples from biblatex-examples.bib.

Comment: Your bibliography style is not set to `chicago-authordate` but to `authoryear` ... I get an error about conflicting options with this anyway ... I also think you are confused about the way `biblatex-chicago` works: it *is* a biblatex format, albeit a slightly special one: and in fact I think you *are* loading it, albeit not in the special way it prefers. An alternative chicago style, more recently developed is `windy-city`.

Comment: And beside of the conflicting-options error there is also a typo in \printbibliography. **Test** your code before asking a question.

Comment: Note that `biblatex-chicago` should usually be called with its wrapper package `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` instead of `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}`. Note further that `style=authoryear, citestyle=chicago-authordate,` means that you are essentially not using Chicago style at all. I am also not sure if using a non-Chicago bibliography style with a Chicago citation style is supported. It should be possible to get split bibliographies and similar things also with `biblatex-chicago` and its wrapper package.

Comment: @moewe @Paul Stanley I did get confused with how to call the style and, in fact setting `style=chicago-authordate` solves the whole problem. I might keep it like that or try calling it with `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}`. In any case, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles of the `biblatex-chicago` package are a bit special in that it is recommended to load them via the special wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` and not via `biblatex` and its `style` option.

Furthermore, in the question you only load `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style for citations, the bibliography is still in the standard `authoryear` style. I can not recommend mixing non-`biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex-chicago` styles.

Since `biblatex-chicago` is for the most part just a thin wrapper around  `biblatex` that sets relevant options, you should be able to do most things you can do with standard `biblatex` also with `biblatex-chicago`. (There is a small difference in the option handling of some options. For example, `biblatex-chicago`'s implementation of the `natbib` compatibility option does not accept a value, but `biblatex`'s version does.)

I suggest you load `biblatex-chicago` as

```
\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber,
            ]{biblatex-chicago}
```

You can add additional options when you have verified that you need them.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber,
            ]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>biblatex-chicago</code> Chicago style]

---

[In the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487334/problems-with-biblatex-and-chicago-parantheses-around-issue-and-duplicated-yea/487347#comment1230803_487334) [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley) mentions a more recent alternative to `biblatex-chicago`: [`windycity`](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity). There are small differences in the output between the two packages, but the general feeling is the same.

`biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style corresponds to `windycity`'s `reflist` option.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=windycity,
            reflist,
            autocite=inline,
            backend=biber,
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>windycity</code> Chicago style]

Comment: Thanks again! Loading `biblatex-chicago` works like a charm now, I'm not entirely sure why I didn't use it before. I am wondering however what the advantage of `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` over `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` are. The differences in the output seem to be very small.

Comment: @Nilsi If you have a look at `biblatex-chicago.sty` you'll find that `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` does an equivalent of `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` and then issues a plethora of options in `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. It is my understanding that some of these settings are required to conform to CMoS guidelines. The package also issues language mappings. Furthermore the package changes a few list and line breaking parameters for the bibliography. ...

Comment: Yes, some of these things may concern only details and the overall difference is probably fairly small for most cases, but it is my understanding that you can only get the full CMoS experience easily and as intended by the author if you load `biblatex-chicago` via the wrapper package. The absence of language mappings if you laod the style manually may mean that some things don't quite work as intended. In any case `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` is redundant and I would reduce it to the equivalent `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}`.

Comment: It seems the wrapper packager does produce the nicer bibliography without having to specify other options. Cheers!

Comment: @Nilsi 'Nicer' is subjective, but if you mean a bibliography that comes close(r) to what the CMoS rules say, then yes, that is pretty much it. The wrapper package already sets some options and applies other settings that make things more Chicago-y.